# Generating Reports in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows application.
I am now concentrating on the Reporting Module of my Application.

I have two ideas to do this task.

Either through Crystal Reports or using the Windows Forms and placing the Data Grid View.

Can any one suggest me which option should I choose?

Also the report should be able to Export in the Excel and PDF format and even it should be Printable.

I heard from others that Crystal Reports gives some problem at the time of Deployment.

Please suggest me. I am very much confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would advise not to use Crystal Reports (or Crusty Reports as they have unfortunately become known as in my department). We have had a whole load of problems from reports being corrupted and requiring recreating to simply being clunky and slow.

As our applications are being upgraded we are moving over to MS Report Viewer, which is far better. You can export to Excel from the report viewer.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2005 and later comes with Microsoft Reporting tools that are so nice and, for me, better than Crystal Reports.

**Update:** You can install the Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable [2005](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=8A166CAC-758D-45C8-B637-DD7726E61367&displaylang=en) or [2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=BB196D5D-76C2-4A0E-9458-267D22B6AAC6&displaylang=en).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Can I know whether I can generate reports from backend MS SQL SERVER?

Will using this as a reporting tool give a problem at the time of deployment?

Please help me!

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server then it is even better to use MS Report Viewer as you have the option of producing your reports using MS Reporting Services (part of SQL Server) and displaying them in the viewer, or simply by creating your reports locally in the viewer.

Comment: I was a former user of Crystal Reports and switched to MS ReportViewer.  I find MS Reporting superior in deployment (much smaller msi, no COM), data binding, and visibility (Crystal .rpt files are binary, rdlc files are xml, which are nicer for source control).  Also as Calanus alludes, with ReportViewer you have the option of switching to SQL Reporting Services (probably with some changes to your .rdlc files).

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). It gives you all the same functionality as Crystal Reports and will let you do your exports into whatever format you like (pdf, csv, txt, xls, etc.) right out of the box. You may run into some problems when trying to export to xls/csv when you are using embedded tables in your reports but microsoft is supposedly fixing this in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating your reports in XML. Later you can decide/change which tool/technology you want to use, without doing much modifications. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out DevExpress Reporting controls, they rock, and are very easy to use.  They also allow you to print to various formats like PDF, they also come with an end-user designer.

[DevExpress Page](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/)

Comment: Crystal Reports is rubbish, many problems encountered when trying to see what versions the customer has - compatibility.
Also, all of their forums are broken since they were bought over by another company, meaning no help either.

Comment: I like DevExpress Tools but it should be noted that they do cost. $350 -$500 depending on your preference.  In some shops(like mine) that is a deal breaker.  FYI

Answer (score 0):

I second the Microsoft Reporting tools.  I am using them extensively in my WinForm App and so far so good.

You can specify whether they processed remotely or locally before deployment.

Here is a link to get you started --> http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-report-with-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you Reporting Services (buid with sql server).
you can develop with VS and publish your reports to Report Server.

Answer (score 0):

Recently abandoned Crystal Reports myself
because of the large number of bugs and crashes
in favor of FastReports. They even have a converter that restored my old reports that were built on Crystal

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.